# scipy truncnorm with array vectors as argumnents for a and b

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

So I need to use the `truncnorm` function in Python to evaluate likelihoods of values from a truncated normal distribution that has a lower bound of zero.

Since `truncnorm` works on the standard normal distribution, `a` and `b` have to be reparameterized if you are using your own `mu` and `sigma` parameters. `a` and `b` are written as `(myclip - mu) / sigma`

I need to evaluate many values at once under different parameterizations of `mu` and `sigma`, which means I have to have arrays as arguments for `a` and `b`. However, every time I do so I get an error message. Some simplified sample code is below:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import truncnorm
v = np.array([5, 4])
mus = np.ones(2)
sigmas = np.ones(2)
a = (0 - mus) / sigmas
b = np.ones(2) * np.inf

like = truncnorm.pdf(vals, a, b, mus, sigmas)
```

And I get this error message:

```
cond0 = self._argcheck(*args) & (scale > 0)
File "/Users/adamosth/anaconda/lib/python2.7/sitepackages/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py", line 3818, in _argcheck
if self.a > 0:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I have no problem if `a` is entered as a single value, but that's not really what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same problem after the update of scipy v0.13 to v0.14. It is still not working in v0.15 (which I have installed right now). So I can confirm your error.

At the moment I use a workaround by looping through all values one by one, which is of course very slow and not a real long term solution. I hope someone has a better suggestion.

Comment: This has been fixed in the more recent scipy versions.